# How to connect to localdb SQL server with pyodbc in Python?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have a local db (localdb\Local_SAR) with a database "master":

[image]

I'm trying to connect to it using pyodbc:

```
server_local = '(local)'
SAR_connection_string_local = 'Driver=SQL Server;Server=%s;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=yes;' %(server_local)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(SAR_connection_string_local)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

I get error:

> OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (2)')

I've tried:

```
server_local = '(localdb\Local_SAR)'
server_local = '(localhost)'
server_local = 'localhost'
server_local = 'local'
```

And get the same error.

If I use a non local server it works, e.g:

```
server_local = 'SQLDEV\DB1'
```

EDIT:

I've managed to make a connection in Powershell using:

```
PS C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn> sqlcmd -S "(localdb)\Local_SAR" -E
```

Which gives:

```
1> select 'hello'
2> go

-----
hello

(1 rows affected)
```

Still not sure how to do it in my python script. Maybe because of the PATH?

Comment: Your picture says the name is `Local_SAR`, not `SAR_Local`.

Comment: Edited, just got mixed up writing the question.

Comment: Which version of LocalDb?

Comment: @Charlieface 13.1

Comment: `(localdb)\Local_SAR` should work according to the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver16#start-localdb-and-connect-to-localdb

Comment: Aside... `'SQLDEV\DB1'` works by accident. In Python the backslash character is an escape character for string literals. You really should be using doubled backslash characters here, otherwise one day you'll collide with one of the natural escape sequences, e.g.: `python -c "print('SQLDEV\rdbms')"` will output to the console what looks like `dbmsEV` because `\r` is the escape sequence for a carriage return character.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the instance using a Python command line script, or from a web page or some other service? Named instances of LocalDB are private to the account that created them, so `(localdb)\Local_SAR` would be accessible to any process executing with your own account credentials, e.g.: `.\mitch`, but would not be accessible to processes executing in a `LocalSystem` context, or in an IIS Application Pool. Ref: [Automatic and named instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/th-th/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb#automatic-and-named-instances)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I'm trying from a local visual studio code python script. So ya should be my own credentials. So should I try ```Integrated Security=true``` instead of ```;Trusted_Connection=yes``` ? (it still gives the same error)